# concatenate string in for windows command

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I want to concatenate to a string in a for command but in every iteration it doesn't update the str as I would want it to do.
the code is:

```
 set x=0
 for %G in (1,2,3) Do set x=%x%1
```

the value I would like x to get is: 0111.

the value accepted is: 01

Comment: Do tou really expect `01`?? I guess you want `0123`... anyway, you'll need delayed expansion, enable it by opening a new command prompt instance with `cmd /V:ON`, then type your commands, but replace `%x%` by `!x!`... (for details, type `cmd /?`)

Answer (score 1):

I made a batch file to test this out and I got 0111 as you expected
here is the batch contents:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set x=0
for %%G in (1,2,3) Do set x=!x!1

echo !x!
pause
```